# flutter to much //ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison in my code

Tags: flutter

Flutter When I migrate package to null-safe, in order to ignore the hints，a lot of // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison  should be use in my code, is these any other way to do this? such as global configuration？ [image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guide in order to migrate to null-safety, It will help you in the process. Use the migration tool in order to convert your code to null-safety

[Migrating to null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide)